# make geth command does not making build of op get

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

i am trying to make build for op-geth but facing the following issue everytime.

eth/protocols/snap/handler.go:472:32: chain.ContractCode undefined (type *core.BlockChain has no field or method ContractCode)
util.go:48: exit status 1
exit status 1
make: *** [Makefile:17: all] Error 1

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you're trying to do.